# empty listbox message wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, message

I have been researching alot and have been trying different ways to display a message when my listbox is empty.

Have done as in this post
[WPF Listbox - Empty List Display Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446903/wpf-listbox-empty-list-display-message)

with no luck have added code in my viewmodel and my textblock locks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding EmptyMessage}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Path=allToDoItemsListBox.Count}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

Have also made a converter that looks like this:

public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null && (int)value > 0)
        return "Collapsed";
    else
        return "Visible";
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

What am i missing, should work but it does not. have added converter in app.xanl to as resource

Comment: Shouldn't your listbox be visible if (int)value > 0, and not the other way around like you did it?

Comment: No. What it says is if the (int)value is grather than 0 it should in this case set the visibility to Collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the returned value is "Collapsed" or "Visible". Shouldn't it be System.Windows.Collapsed and System.Windows.Visible ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this Code:

```
    public object Convert(object Value, Type TargetType, object Parameter, CultureInfo Culture)
    {
        if (value != null && (int)value > 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

For this please check if you have the following using declaration

```
using System.Windows;
```

Comment: Try debugging and set a breakpoint on both of the return-lines. Does the debugger go there? Else it seems to be a problem with the declaration of your Converter as a ressource.

Comment: Tested this and the debugger does not go there. My declaration of my Converter resource is in my app.xaml and look like this: 
 
<Application.Resources>
        <converter:VisibilityConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:mechanics" x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: Move the definition of the converter (xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:mechanics") upwards, directly as an attribute of the Application Tag. I think yours doesn't work because the definition of converter: is below the actual use of it.

Comment: I moved the definition of the converter and that did the trick. big thanks for the help.

Comment: please set this as answer so this will help others with the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the textBlock Visibility to a property such as this:

```
public System.Windows.Visibilty EmptyMessageVisibility
{
    get { return itemList.Count == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; }
}
```

Comment: So my visibility binding on my textblock using the converter is no use then ? I have tested with the example you show but when i set my listbox as where the itemList is there is no property that says Count. Am i a bit blind here.

Comment: For ListBox it is listBox.Items.Count

Comment: i thougth i was so smart when i tried using ObservableColletion as in this post 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/f7fd9f30-4a4f-4a84-8481-4d6adb672346

Did not work so god, when i add items they never show.

Comment: You must not have the DataContext or the Binding set right. If you post more code it would help.